# Is it possible to get $_FILES["inputID"]["tmp_name"] from a file field using javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, html, file-upload

I have an input field:

```
<input type="file" id="inputID" name="file">
```

When a button is clicked to submit, a JavaScript function will run (url: upload.php). I need to be able to access `$_FILES["inputID"]["tmp_name"]` from this input field so that I could use it on `upload.php` as,

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["inputID"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)
```

Is this possible? 
At the moment, I get an error:

> Notice: Undefined index: inputID

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Thanks so much! :-)

Comment: If your `<input>` name is `file` then you need `$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]` in PHP, and since that's on the server you cannot access it from JavaScript.

Comment: It's not possible, unless you store that value with php into somewhere and make an ajax request afterwards to get the information.

Comment: You don't even have a field called `inputID`. I think you should edit the question and explain *what* you need to do rather than *how*...

Answer (score 3):

`move_uploaded_file()` is a php function, running on a PHP-based server-side application.

It is handled by PHP when your form has been submitted.

You cannot access it from JavaScript before it has been sent, whatever would be the way you would submit it, both asynchronously with an XHR Request, or directly submitting the form to its handler route.

Answer (score 0):

you can access it after it is submitted, although I don't see why you should:

```
<?php
...
$tmpname=$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]
...
?>
...
<script>
var tmpname = <?=$tmpname?>
...
</script>
...
```

I'm not clear on what you are trying to do. If you want some ajax upload functionality It's better to use a js library.

Comment: This method assumes to first submit the form with the selected file.
Then you render the form again, displaying the tmp_name handled by PHP.
However, even if you indeed access it with JavaScript, the tmp_name will change at any new HTTP request, so you cannot rely on it to call the server once again with it.

Comment: I agree that it's useless, but it is accessible nevertheless.

Comment: Strictly talking, I guess yes. But as you say, I do not see any utility of using it :)